# How can we get values of dynamic element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<td class="invert-price">${{$cartProduct->product_price}}</td>
```

JQuery

```
    $('.value-plus').on('click', function(){
    var divUpd = $(this).parent().find('.value'), newVal = parseInt(divUpd.text(), 10)+1;
    divUpd.text(newVal);
    var plus = $(".invert-price").html();
    if(plus.charAt( 0 ) === '$' )
    plus = plus.slice( 1 );
    plus = plus*2;
    $(".invert-price-").html('$'+plus);                                                                           
    });
```

I changed td class.

```
<td class="invert-price-{{$cartProduct->id}}">${{$cartProduct->product_price}}</td>
```

table->tr

```
  @foreach($cartProducts as $cartProduct)
                <tr class="rem{{$cartProduct->id}}">
                    <td class="invert">{{$count}}</td>
                    <td class="invert-image"><a href="single.html">{{ Html::image('upload/product/'.$cartProduct->product_image, $cartProduct->product_image,['height'=> '200','width'=>'200','class'=>'img-responsive']) }}</a></td>
                    <td class="invert">
                         <div class="quantity"> 
                            <div class="quantity-select">                           
                                <div class="entry value-minus">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="entry value"><span>1</span></div>
                                <div class="entry value-plus active">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="invert">{{$cartProduct->product_name}}</td>
                    <td class="invert">$5.00</td>
                    <td class="invert-price-{{$cartProduct->id}}">${{$cartProduct->product_price}}</td>
                    <td class="invert">
                        <div class="rem">
                            <div class="close1" data-id="{{$cartProduct->id}}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <script>$(document).ready(function(c) {
                            $('.close1').on('click', function(c){
                                                                var id = $(this).data("id");
                                                                 var token = $(this).data("token");
                                                         $.ajax({
                                                                                url: "removeCartItem/"+id,
                                                                                type: 'DELETE',
                                                                                dataType: "JSON",
                                                                                data: {
                                                                                    "id": id,
                                                                                    "_method": 'DELETE',
                                                                                    "_token": token,
                                                                                },
                                                                               success: function ()
                                                                                {
                                                                                    $('.rem'+ id).fadeOut('slow');
                                                                                }
                                                                                });
                                });
                            });
                       </script>
                    </td>
                </tr> <?Php $count++; ?>
                                    @endforeach
```

What i want is that when i click on increment button price got doubled in my case price got doubled of every price element(td). So i added id with td class  class="invert-price-{{$cartProduct->id}}". I don't know how to get values of dynamic element using jquery. So please help me.

Comment: Please show more of your html. If the `.value-plus` item that you're clicking is in the same `<tr>` as the `.invert-price` then you don't need unique ids, you can use DOM navigation methods to find the related item in the same row (the same as you already do for `divUpd`).

Comment: yes it is same in same row one min i update question

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer now, but (a) do what I mentioned in my previous comment, what you're already doing to some degree, and (b) don't include that `<script>` element inside your `@foreach` or you'll bind multiple click handlers to the same elements.